# Get Username of current addin user

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in

Lets say a user opened a solution in VS.
How can I get the username of the current user using Visual Studio 2010 add-in?

I searched in the MSDN but still couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the user name defined by the environment

```
string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

Comment: +1 Oh my god, I'm embarrassed, I had never thought about it before. Thank you jared

Answer (score 1):

You mean the username of the person logged in to the machine?

[This may answer your question](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/214216-get-current-user-name-system)

From that link, Environment.UserName seems to work.